# U-SQL ONLY extract specific data from JSON

Tags: c#, json, u-sql, jsonparser

I have a JSON file which contains an array of objects

```
{
  [ 
    {id:1, a:4},
    {id:2, a:7},
    {id:3, a:5},
    {id:4, a:9}
  ]    
}
```

How can i write a U-SQL script to extract only the first object `{id:1, a:4}`

Couldn't find on the docs of the JSON Assembly if JsonExtractor actually took as an argument a JSONPath string, but it does take a string and for what a read on other posts, its a JSONPath *like* string

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats]; 

USING Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json;

DECLARE @InputPath string = "filepath.json"

@RawData = 
    EXTRACT id     int,
            a      int
    FROM @InputPath
    USING new JsonExtractor("$[:1]");
```

**NOTE**: This objects are not the real objects. My requirements are to get the first of the array. There is no possible where field to match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer.

Turns out that JsonExtract does receive a string parameter which is a JSONPath, **but** when you use a file like shown, where the first element is an unnamed array, it assumes that each object is a different JSON.

Here you can find the [issue](https://github.com/Azure/usql/issues/118) that states the problem

---

To my concern, you have **2 ways out**:

Implement your own extractor that handles this case.

**or**

**Rebuild your input JSON** if you can, so as to name the array.

```
{
  data: [ 
    {id:1, a:4},
    {id:2, a:7},
    {id:3, a:5},
    {id:4, a:9},
  ]
}
```

and then you can use a JsonPath to extract a specific part of the json like so

```
@RawData = 
  EXTRACT id     int,
          a      int
  FROM @InputPath
  USING new JsonExtractor("$.data[0]");
```

Getting as a result `id: 1, a:4`

Answer (score 0):

If the value 'id' is always sequential starting from 1 you can use a WHERE clause:

```
@RawData = 
    EXTRACT id     int,
            a      int
    FROM @InputPath
    USING new USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor();

@CleanData
    SELECT  id    int,
            a     int
    FROM @RawData
    WHERE id == 1;
```

Comment: I need to be done on the extraction, there are no where clasues that satisfy my needs, i just need the first on the array